# Always day and always night - a riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Can anyone solve this riddle?

> Always day and always night,
>   You'll know me when you see the light.
>   But don't look up, don't mess around -
>   In these words is where I may be found.
>   Through eternity ever I flowed,
>   Beyond the marble you call your abode.
>   I am warm and I am cold;
>   Visit me if you are bold.
>   If you are confused sometimes,
>   Just relax, read between the lines.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Space.

Always day and always night,

> Day and night are properties of planets with a sun, but space contains all of these planets, including both the parts in day and the parts in night.

You'll know me when you see the light.

> We [mostly] see light through empty space.

But don't look up, don't mess around -

> Ceilings and the light sky by day obscure our view of space.

In these words is where I may be found.

> Spaces between these words.

Through eternity ever I flowed,

> Space has [probably] existed as long as time has.

Beyond the marble you call your abode.

> Space surrounds the Earth (the marble) that's our home.

I am warm and I am cold;

> Space has no temperature, but places in space will be very hot and very cold.

Visit me if you are bold.

> Brave the final frontier.

If you are confused sometimes,

> Spaced out.

Just relax, read between the lines.

> Spaces between the lines.

Answer (score 6):

> Space

> It is in the source code :-)

*Edit:*  
@downvoters, the question was/is if anyone can solve this and there were/are no other restrictions. So i choosed the easiest way for me [looking up the source code].

*Edit 2:*

> [image: Source Code]

Comment: where in the source code?!

Comment: In the `riddle.js` there is an array called possAns => `possible Answers`

Comment: it's encrypted but yes: 0803df4ff1650933d2ffe6be04d4b21432134252

Comment: @d'alar'cop Look at my second edit.

Comment: Who cares if it's in the source code?  This is so howlingly obviously contrary to the spirit of a riddle.

Comment: I care! This is my way to solve a riddle, looking up the code understand the way it is handled etc. Kind of a riddle by itself.
I don't think there is the one and only right way to solve a riddle, especially when there are no restrictions by the OP.

Comment: Looks like legitimate lateral-thinking to me. The question didn't say no computers.

Comment: It was actually clever when you explained, I thought you flat out copied from the site. So, downvote reverted to upvote.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/riddle/info